# Prestashop Webservice get Product combinations

Tags: web-services, combinations, prestashop, product

Hi I have a little question about these product combinations in prestashop. We are implementing a integration for our Warehouse Management System that imports products from prestashop via Webservice.

Now to the problem. Lets say there are a t-shirt with different sizes Small, Medium, Large.

If i import with /api/products?display=full I got only one id for the sizes. How should i Map for example a tshirt Small with a unique id.

Some example i thaught of was if it was possible to combine the product id for example 1 with combination 14 than it will be 114. But its not a safe way because it may be a product id 11 with combination 4.

And in order import i got product attribute id. How to map it to correct combination?

Comment: Did you try `/api/combinations`? It is listed in the [Web service reference](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Web+service+reference).

Comment: I think i Solved it As you say, i used the combination and product_option names as the product name and maps id_product_attribute as combination id for the system to know wich product to ship.